# C# Daylight saving DateTime switch

Tags: c#

I have events that get triggered whenever the daylight switches happen.

I get when the spring/fall switches are going to happen using

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(year)
```

This returns me 2 datetimes:
1. Start Datetime which is Spring cutover
3. End Datetime which is the Fall cutover.

The Spring forward works fine.

But for the Fall one the End Time I get is 2.00 AM CST. So when I subtract a second from I get 1.59.59 AM CST. So the event gets fired an hour later. I need to set the trigger for 1.59.59 CDT. How do I construct this Datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to set it for 1 second before the start of the time change. Convert to UTC, then subtract the delta and another second.

```
DateTime fall; //set to 2:00 AM CST
DaylightTime time; //Filled from your GetDaylightChanges() call.
DateTime fallAdjusted = fall.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(time.Delta).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Comment: Agreed, use UTC. What you're trying to do is use a time that doesn't actually exist.